# Access Instance Variable through Ajax Requests and Partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Within my application I can add an object to my `CartItem` model but am getting `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`, when destroying the record and rendering my view via Ajax.

So upon page load `/images/7` for example I have

```
<div id="cart_form">
  <% if @cart_item_collection.include?(@image.id) %>
    <%= render 'shared/forms/remove_from_cart', locals: { image: @image } %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'shared/forms/add_to_cart', locals: { image: @image } %>
  <% end %>
</div>

class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @cart_item_collection = CartItem.where(user_id: current_or_guest_user).pluck(:image_id)
  end
end
```

_add_to_cart.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@cart_item, url: cart_item_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :image_id, value: @image.id %>
   <%= f.submit "Add To Cart" %>
<% end %>
```

_remove_from_cart.html.erb

```
<%=button_to cart_item_path(id: @cart_item), method: :delete, :remote => true, class: "icon di_darckblue extra-large button fill", name: 'images' do %>
<i class="di-shopping-cart-up"></i>
Remove From Cart
```

As  previously mentioned I can create a CartItem fine, I render this js.erb file

```
$("#cart_form").html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/forms/remove_from_cart', locals: { image: @image } %>");
```

But when I try to destroy the CartItem thats when I get the error

```
$("#cart_form").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/forms/add_to_cart", locals: { image: @image } %>');
```

How can I keep @image persisted throughout each call?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to pass image id when making AJAX calls so that the @image object can be obtained in the views when partials are getting rendered on AJAX completion.

Therefore we fetch the `@image` using the image_id parameter.

**show.html.erb**

```
<div id="cart_form">
  <% if @cart_item_collection.include?(@image.id) %>
    <%= render 'shared/forms/remove_from_cart', locals: { image: @image } %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'shared/forms/add_to_cart', locals: { image: @image } %>
  <% end %>
  <p class="error"></p>
</div>
```

**images_controller.rb**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @cart_item_collection = CartItem.where(user_id: current_or_guest_user).pluck(:image_id)
  end
end
```

**_add_to_cart.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@cart_item, url: cart_item_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :image_id, value: @image.id %>
   <%= f.submit "Add To Cart" %>
<% end %>
```

**_remove_from_cart.html.erb**

```
<%=button_to cart_item_path(id: @cart_item, image_id: @image.id), method: :delete, :remote => true, class: "icon di_darckblue extra-large button fill", name: 'images' do %>
<i class="di-shopping-cart-up"></i>
Remove From Cart
```

**Adding to cart**,

```
def add_to_cart
    @image = Image.find(params[:cart_item][:image_id])
    #if @image is present
      #your code
    #else
       #@error= "Item could not be added to cart."
    #end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
<% if !@error %>
    $("#cart_form").html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/forms/remove_from_cart', locals: { image: @image } %>");
    $('.error').html('');
<% else %>
    $('.error').html(<%= @error %>);
<% end %>
```

**Removing from cart,**

```
def destroy
    @image = Image.find(params[:image_id])
    #if @image
      #destroying @cart_item
      #rendering destroy.js.erb
      #@cart_item = CartItem.new
    #else
      @error="Item could not be removed from cart"
    #end 
end
```

destroy.js.erb:

```
<% if !@error %>
    $("#cart_form").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/forms/add_to_cart", locals: { image: @image } %>');
    $('.error').html('');
<% else %>
    $('.error').html(<%= @error %>);
<% end %>
```

**Another way:**
As you are just using image id inside the partials: 
here we are just passing the image_id in controller and sending it back to front end.

But the only check that we would have to do is checking if the image exists for the image_id passed to controller, as there are chances that user can change the value in front end.

To check that we would have to check for presence of image on every AJAX call made, which makes the first approach more safer. But if that doesn't matter to you then you can go with this approach.

```
<div id="cart_form">
  <% if @cart_item_collection.include?(@image.id) %>
    <%= render 'shared/forms/remove_from_cart', locals: { image_id: @image.id } %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'shared/forms/add_to_cart', locals: { image_id: @image.id } %>
  <% end %>
</div>

class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @cart_item_collection = CartItem.where(user_id: current_or_guest_user).pluck(:image_id)
  end
end
```

_add_to_cart.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@cart_item, url: cart_item_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :image_id, value: image_id %>
   <%= f.submit "Add To Cart" %>
<% end %>
```

_remove_from_cart.html.erb

```
<%=button_to cart_item_path(id: @cart_item, image_id: image_id), method: :delete, :remote => true, class: "icon di_darckblue extra-large button fill", name: 'images' do %>
<i class="di-shopping-cart-up"></i>
Remove From Cart
```

**Adding to cart, I render this js.erb file,**

```
def add_to_cart
    @image_id = params[:cart_item][:image_id]
    #your code

end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#cart_form").html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/forms/remove_from_cart', locals: { image_id: @image_id } %>");
```

**Removing from cart,**

```
def destroy
    @image = params[:image_id]
    #destroying @cart_item
    #rendering destroy.js.erb
end
```

**destroy.js.erb:**

```
$("#cart_form").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/forms/add_to_cart", locals: { image_id: @image_id } %>');
```

Comment: isnt the fact that im getting `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` on @image mean that @image inst available or doesn't exist ?

Comment: and would this check be on _add_to_cart.html.erb ?

Comment: So if an item is removed from cart, what happens to the image? Are you passing it from `def remove_from_cart` method?

Comment: You are passing, `image` inside both the partials, but you are trying to access `@image`. On general page load it doesn't give any error as the instance is present, but when doing it through AJAX, that object will not be present anymore.

Comment: So do i need to reference `image.id` instead of `@image.id` ? I need @image to be available when creating and destroying. I'm a little confused

Comment: Yes, `image` object will be available in the form, the `image_id` field in the form will have the `image` id.

Comment: Thanks for the update, is it bad practice though to persist Instance varibles ?

Comment: Yes, one should not use too many instance variables unless the object is needed to be accessed somewhere else, as it uses memory. Is it working for you now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99687/discussion-between-richlewis-and-sahil).

Comment: thanks for the update, the only bit i dont quite understand is `@image = Image.find(params[:cart_item][:image_id])`

Comment: In add_to_cart form, you have one hidden field `cart_item[image_id]`, which is getting passed in backend on submitting. So, we use that image id to get the image from controller again to view.

Comment: yes it is working, thank you, but as previously mentioned not quite sure why @image = Image.find(params[:cart_item][:image_id]) is there

Comment: As I can see in your current code, you can pass, `image_id: @image.id` in your partial inside `locals` as you just need the image id. Shall I write another way where you dont have to fetch image again and again?

Comment: yes i would like to know how to approach this correctly please, I appreciate your time on this

Comment: Please check it now.